# Custom Button Receives Border When Form NOT Focused

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've seen a lot of issues for people that mouseover a button and get an unwanted border.

However, my problem is different.  My button acts exactly how I want it to with custom images, mouseover and click.  My problem is that when I generate more then one form, each additional form's button has a border around it unless I focus that **form**, then the border goes away.

Any clue what could be causing this?

[image: Button Example Image]
<sub>(source: [tec-systems.com](http://www.tec-systems.com/external/buttonexample.jpg))</sub>

1. BackColor - Transparent
2. BackgroundImage - none
3. FlatAppearance

   - BorderColor - Blank
   - BorderSize - 0
   - MouseDown - Transparent
   - MouseOver - Transparent
4. FlatStyle - Flat

I would appreciate any insight!

Comment: Well, at least I earned the Tumbleweed badge!

Here's a sample project that shows my issue:

http://www.tec-systems.com/external/buttonissue.rar

Comment: Should I just change it to a picturebox or something?

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the issue

> button.TabStop = false;

Comment: Almost 10 years for an answer!  LOL!  These were notification windows and they eventually got swapped out with something more robust.  So I have no way of testing this.  If it ever comes up again I've added your fix to my internal wiki.  Thanks Rajesh!